# People picker: Use a specific `<input>` and attributes

Tags: people-picker, angularjs

I am currently using AngularJS.
And so I wish to have AngularJS attributes on my people picker `<input>`s.

[A first example: Data binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts); shows how simple it is to use `<input>`s with no hassle in getting or setting input data.

```
<div ng-app ng-init="qty=1;cost=2">
    <b>Invoice:</b>
    <div>
        Quantity: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="qty">
    </div>
    <div>
        Costs: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="cost">
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>Total:</b> {{qty * cost | currency}}
    </div>
</div>
```

However I do not know how I can use AngularJS with SharePoint's people picker, `SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper`.
This is as it overwrote an `<input>` that I gave in the `<div>`.
And as far as I know `InitStandaloneControlWrapper` is the only way to make a people picker.

Below is an example of what I hoped would work, but did not.

```
<div id="peoplePickerDiv">
    <input ng-model="myAngularInput" >
</div>
```

So if I haven't made the problem clear enough.
Is there a way to force `SPClientPeoplePicker` to use a given `<input>`.
The `<input>` also has to retain the attributes given to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a people picker by customizing [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/).

**view**

```
<tags-input ng-model="vm.newTask.assignedUsers"
                    display-property="Name"
                    placeholder="Pick User"
                    add-from-autocomplete-only="true"
                    replace-spaces-with-dashes="false">
            <auto-complete source="vm.getPeoplePickerSuggestion($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

**controller**

```
vm.newTask = {
    assignedUsers: []
};
vm.getPeoplePickerSuggestion = function(searchString) {
    return demoAppSvc.getPeoplePickerSuggestion(searchString)
        .then(function(response) {
            var results = response.d.results;
            return results.filter(function(user) {
                return user.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) != -1;
            });
        });
};
```

**service**

```
function getPeoplePickerSuggestion(searchKey) {
    var userSearchSuggestionEndpoint = "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList?
        $select=Id,Name&$filter=substringof('" + searchKey + "',Name)";
    return baseSvc.getRequest(userSearchSuggestionEndpoint);
}
```

Also see my [article in code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1008871/Developing-Custom-Date-Picker-People-Picker-and-Ch) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use client-side people picker control for SharePoint wrapped in an AngularJS directive

there are few links which may help you

https://github.com/jasonvenema/sharepoint-angular-peoplepicker
https://github.com/matthewyarlett/AngularJS-Directive-for-SharePoint-People-Picker